# HOCON: multiple reference.conf resolution issue

Tags: hocon

I have multi-module project under SBT.

Project `A` (library) has `reference.conf` file with `A`'s configuration parameters. Project `A` depends on `akka-actor` library, which ships with its own `reference.conf` file. Project `A` redefines some `akka`'s parameters in own `reference.conf`.

Project `B` depends on `A`.

When I call `ConfigFactory.load()` in `B`, I'm getting wrong order of `reference.conf`s merging. It first takes `A`'s config, then applies `akka-actor`'s config over it. Eventually, I'm getting initial `akka-actor`'s configuration.

How can I fix it? I need to get `akka-actor`'s config loaded first, then my `A`'s config should be applied over it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your config that you are trying to load and the code you are using to load it?

Comment: @cmbaxter There is too much code to demonstrate. But nothing special. I suppose it's common behavior of `ConfigFactory.load()`. Documentation claims: it will apply all `reference.conf` files in classpath. But it didn't specify in what order. I'm looking the way how to specify concrete order of application `reference.conf` files.

Comment: When I want to override standard conf from akka, I do it via application.conf and not reference.conf

Comment: I would think that `reference.conf` is for the applications own configuration, not for **overriding** configuration in a transient dependency library. As I recall it there are no guarantees about class path ordering, so you can probably not protect against it in any other way than to override settings elsewhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, looks like I've found the answer in sources of `ConfigFactory`.

All the `reference.conf` is being loaded through `ClassLoader.getResources`. It returns `java.util.Enumeration[URL]`. The order of `URL`s in this enum is the answer to the question. So all you need to do: ensure the order of your `reference.conf` resources in this enumeration properly arranged.

Here is an example of how to do that. First, create your own version of `ClassLoader` by overriding `getResources` method:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

class CustomClassLoader(loader: ClassLoader) extends ClassLoader(loader){
    override def getResources(name: String): util.Enumeration[URL] = {
        val resources = super.getResources(name).asScala.toList
        // arrange resources as you wish here
        java.util.Collections.enumeration(resources.asJava)
    }
}
```

Last, call `load` method of `ConfigFactory` with your `CustomClassLoader` instance.

Comment: How did you manage to arrange resources in this method? Do you rely on URL's `getPath` method?

Comment: @maks I've figured out the order to load config files. Then I've arranged the list of resources according to that order. That's it. And yes, I'd relied on URL which contains name and path to the config files.